# Copy to and from comment

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I copied a working piece of code to the comment under one of recent questions:

```
Histogram[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 2}],   Above] &)
]
```

After copying it back it was not recognized as a correct input

> [image]
>
> [image]

Have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: `Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 2}], 
     Above] &)]`

Comment: The same happens with this code ^ but not the one from the question body.

Comment: Bizarre.  Happens in both V10.4 and V11 (Max OS X 10.11.6).

Comment: @MichaelE2 which probably means the problem is on SE side.

Comment: Yeah, it's an SE issue; SE inserts [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) non-printing characters between certain letters like i and o, r and i, and even # and ",". It's supposed to be used to prevent ligatures from forming, for example preventing "ae" from turning into "æ", but this must be a mistake.

Comment: That explains why some code I copied from comments didn't work, but when I re-typed it all was fine.  I didn't investigate though.

Comment: @C.E. I know, SE team don't want people to answer in comments! :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert

Comment: So this should work: `Histogram[ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], 
 LabelingFunction -> ( 
   Placed[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 2}], Above] &)]`

Comment: but it does not.

Comment: @Kuba The longest run in that is 35 characters.  So perhaps something went wrong with SE recently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add to what @Szabolcs said, we made a change on Monday to accommodate non-English sites and reduced the interval between gaps to 20.

We since changed it to be every 20 characters, *only after a sequence of 60 characters without any space or return*. So this should be fixed. Note that this was only a *rendering* difference, so the original comments have never been altered and should be fine now.

Please double check if there are more edge cases, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To summarize the findings so far:

StackExchange does insert unicode characters U+200C (zero width non joiner) and U+200B (zero width space) into comments on occasion.  [Link to Meta.SE post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert)  This is done for reasons related to how browsers do line breaking.

In the linked Meta.SE thread it is stated that this is done only when there is a run of at least 80 non-whitespace characters.  However, in the examples shown under the post above, we don't have such a long run of non-whitespace characters!  In @Kuba's comment the longest run is 35.

[image]

This makes me suspect that there is a recent change in how comments are handled.  Perhaps a bug?  It would be good to have an answer from the SE staff.

Incidentally, [there was a question today](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124193/12) about a non-working command which is broken exactly due to an invisible zero-width space.  The OP claims that he didn't copy any part of that command from a comment, but the coincidence in timing makes me wonder ...

Comment: This was also a problem for math.SE, when people were posting long LaTeX expressions in comments and wondering why MathJax was failing on them.